# Why does the submenu display behind the images(displayed using bxslider) when I hover over the navigation menu?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bxslider

I am using *****bxslider***** for carousels and its below the *navigation menu*, when I hover over the menu to display the *submenu*, it displays but items below hide behind the images.I expected the submenu to be displayed infront of the images(as it works when images are not in a slide show).When I add multiple  br tags between the menu and the image slider there is space for the submenu to be displayed but this is not what I want.
When the screen size is adjusted to mobile view there are no issues as I use slicknav.

Comment: You should set z-index of submenu bigger than other items.

Comment: I have set the z-index for only the submenu and it has worked out! Thanks